# How to Update User data if user not uploaded Profile Picture In api call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-s3, alamofire

I'm creating an app where in user can update user profile. But what if user don't want to change image and only made changes in first name or last name , But not change profile picture. can Please some guide me , I'm using Alamofire and awss3 for upload image , Here's my code

```
func saveProfile(imagename: String )
{
    
    if self.firstNameTxt.text!.isEmpty || self.lastNameTxt.text!.isEmpty || self.birthDateTxt.text!.isEmpty   {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please Fill All THE FIELDS", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    } else {
        let parameter : Parameters = [
            
            "first_name": self.firstNameTxt.text!,
            "last_name": self.lastNameTxt.text!,
            "birth_date" : self.birthDateTxt.text!,
            "profile_pic" : imagename
        ]
        
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        
        MVCServer().serviceRequestWithURL(reqMethod: .patch, withUrl: "user-profile", withParam: parameter, diplayHud: true, includeToken: true) { responseCode, response in
            if responseCode == 1 {
                if let dataResponse =  response.value(forKey: "result") as? Bool , let payload = response.value(forKey: "payload") as? NSDictionary{
                    if dataResponse  == true {
                        
                        if let userData = LoginModel.init(dictionary: payload) {
                            Utility.setModelObject(userData , forKey: ProfileData)
                            self.view.makeToast("Profile Updated Succefully", duration: 3.0, position: .top)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                Utility.showMessage("Error", withTitle: "Error While Uploading Data", on: self)
                print(response.value(forKey: "message") as? String ?? "")
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

this is my save button action

```
 @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    uploadImage()
   
}
```

And Here i'm calling Uploading Image Api.

```
func uploadImage()
{
    if let profileImageData = profileImageData
    {
        let imageName:Int64  = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        let randomString = Utility.getAlphaNumericRandomNumber()
        let imageNameStr = String(format:"%@%d.jpg",randomString,imageName)
        let stringUploadPath = String(format:"%@/%@",AmazonAWS3.S3UploadPathProfile,imageNameStr)
        Utility.showLoadingView()
        AmazonAWS3().uploadFileToAWS3(filePath: stringUploadPath, data: profileImageData) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                self.saveProfile(imagename: imageNameStr)
            case .failure(_):
                
                print("Error While Uploading Image")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: this is My Ui Looks Like.]

Comment: What exactly do you want if the user doesn't change the profile pic and only changes the other info?

Comment: call function for only data updating without image. I mean only name or last name should change only.

Comment: You need to handle this with 2 boolean values, you can check any of the user data fields that got changed by comparing the new values with old values. And same for avatar change as soon as the user changes the avatar and it gets set on the profile image change the boolean accordingly and call API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way according to your implementation would be using a dictionary inside your VC (or VM or where you need to) that stores the updated value that your user has changed.

```swift
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet var lastNameLabel: UILabel!

   var updatedValues: [String : String] = [:] // or [String : Any] 

   // If you are using Storyboard you need to link the IBOutlet to the value changed event
   @IBOutlet func firstName_onChange(_ sender: UILabel) {
      // do some validation 
      updatedValues["first_name"] = sender.text
   }

   // Same outlet for lastName and birthdate

}
```

For your image, it's a bit unclear how you generate the `imagename` but you could use the same approach. When the user selects a picture from the gallery you can update the `updatedValues` by adding the `profile_pic` key/value consequently.

At the moment of doing the `saveProfile` your `updatedValues` should contain only what the user has changed and if contains the `profile_pic` key you also invoke the `uploadImage`